# forward domain name to particular page?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, domain

I;ve got a doman alias setup for one of my Wordpress sites and i'm trying to forward that particular domain to a page.

The 2 domains are -

www.alias.com
www.actual.com
When people use the *www.alias.com* domain i want them to be forwarded to *www.alias.com/content/*

I've tried several things with the htaccess file but i think Worpdress may be ignoring the redirects or i've got it completely wrong!

ie

```
Redirect 301 www.alias.com http://www.alias.com/content/

# and
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.alias.com
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.alias.com/content/ [R=301,L]
```

best, Dc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off -- does your server allow overrides in `.htaccess` files?  If not, you need to get that turned on.  My server has `AllowOverride All` set in its config file, which then allows my `.htaccess` rules to function.

Does `alias.com` point to the same directory as `actual.com`?  If not, then you need to put a `.htaccess` file in the `alias.com` root.

Also, if I understand your requirements correctly, the `.htaccess` file for `alias.com` needs to contain this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.alias.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.actual.com/content/ [R=301,L]
```

#### References

Apache's [Config File](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#htaccess) & 
[URL Rewriting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost) docs

I also have a mod_rewrite from http://www.ilovejackdaniels.com/ but that site seems to be down now.

Comment: Hey Pat - set AllowOverride All but still nothing happens. Both domains point to the same directory. Code im using is; RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.indy8.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.indy8.com/content/ [R=301,L]. I want to keep the alias domain in the address bar for this page if possible.

Comment: Did you restart your web server after setting `AllowOverride All`?  Also, I think the `301` redirection will change the browser's address bar to reflect the new URL, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: yeh i did. Can't seem to find a quick way of testing if AllowOverride is working. Feels like this should be pretty straightforward!

Comment: ok - i'm an idiot. Just moved the site to a new server but ftp was pointing to old server! Used this in the end - RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.indy8.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.indy8.com/content/$1 [R=301,L]. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't count the number of times I've made a mistake like that... Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a WordPress question and still on the first position in Google, I'll add a not-so-technical solution for the scenario:

Today there are redirect-plugins that you can use - no need to modify an htaccess file or other server configuration.

### WPMU DEV SmartCrawl

I use SmartCrawl for those cases, like this:

[image: smartcrawl pro]

### Related Links

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/smartcrawl-seo/ (free version, can do those redirects)
- https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/smartcrawl-wordpress-seo/ (premium version for WPMU DEV members)

Note: *I'm not affiliated with WPMU DEV, I just like their products.*